# How to save whether a user clicked a button or not, and if so run a function

Tags: javascript, onclick, conditional-statements, local-storage, onclicklistener

I have two functions translate_fr and translate_en, onClick when you click FR or EN the paragraphs are swapped either to english or french by grabbing their id's with inner.html

[image]

These two functions run on every html page, but obviously when refreshed or changing pages the onclick function reverts back to normal. So for instance if the user presses the FR button I want all the translate_fr functions on the other pages to run once the page loads, swapping the english paragraphs to french.

I need a way to store the users button click with local storage, and then a conditional statement saying if the user pressed EN run function translate_en else if FR then run function translate_fr.

Is this possible? I am VERY new to JavaScript and unfamiliar with local storage. I have no way how to do this. Here is the website on its domain  lionkuts.ca for any other reference. I put two paragraphs as an example, though as you can see in the image I did this for every paragraph in the website.

```js
function translate_en(){
document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = `Here at Lion Kuts we are a cat only establishment that offers a full range of services from complete grooming, bathing to boarding. You and your pet will be thrilled to know that only professional, natural and biodegradeable products are used, any sensitivities or allergies will not be a problem.`;
}
   
function translate_fr(){
document.getElementById("intro").innerHTML = `Chez Coupe Lion, nous ne sommes qu'un chat établissement offrant une gamme complète de services du toilettage complet, de la baignade à l'embarquement.Vous et votre animal sera ravi de savoir que seul un professionnel, des produits naturels et biodégradables sont utilisés, tout les sensibilités ou les allergies ne seront pas un problème.`;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper3">
   <button class="translate" id="click1"            type="button"onclick="translate_en()">EN
   </button> 

   <button class="translate" id="click2" 
   type="button" onclick="translate_fr()">FR
   </button>
 </div>
 
    <p id="intro">
      Here at Lion Kuts we are a cat only
      establishment that offers a full range of services 
      from complete grooming, bathing to boarding. You and 
      your pet will be thrilled to know that only professional, 
      natural and biodegradeable products are used, any 
      sensitivities or allergies will not be a problem.
  </p>
```

Comment: documentation can help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Been reading up on it , I have an idea of how to piece everything together but don't know where to begin. I know I can store whether or not a user pressed a button, then on every other page have a body onload function. That function being a conditional statement saying if localstoragetitem is == to EN run function translate_en or else run function translate_FR. Still unfamiliar with syntax amongst other things so I definitely need a kick in the right direction.

Comment: you described exaclty what you need to do. `onclick` save (`.setItem()`)  on page load load what you need (`.getItem()`) . If the variable that receives the getItem is null, then it means no value stored

Comment: At least I am on the right path, I went to school for front-end, just finished the course on Javascript but it was only 2 weeks!! So I need more time for sure, another course before I am even comfortable :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use Window.localStorage to save the current language, and then use Window.onload to check the language.
[Window.localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)
[Window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event)

```js
function translate_en(){
    Window.localStorage.setItem("language", "EN");
    //translate the web page
} //translate_fr is same, but with french

Window.onload = (e) => {
    let language = Window.localStorage.getItem("language");
    if(language === "EN"){
        translate_en();
    } else if(language === "FR"){
        translate_fr();
    } else {
        translate_en();//Default (if null)
    }
}
```

Comment: As I commented to calvin nunes, I think this is what I am looking for

Comment: @2pichar Wow man, I managed to code it for him but it was like 30 lines of new code while you did it in a few lines. :D

Comment: Can I see what you did?

Comment: The Window.localStorage allows you to access the local storage for that web page, and so you can access it from anything on that domain. when the user clicks the button, it sets the local storage to the appropriate identifier, and then when the page loads on any of them, it checks the local storage for the language id, and translates it appropriately.

Comment: @gears244 https://codepen.io/tadaspuleikis/pen/MWvBebm